# Анализ фотографии/перевод изображения в массив байтов/Быстрое обращение к пикселям

Tags: c#, изображения, анализ, обработка-изображений

В ходе написания программы для анализа Дифракционных картин возник тупик.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не получается быстро  и правильно работать с пикселями фотографии.

Пока был прототип, устраивало GetPixel, но теперь... Испробовал 4 способа. Все возвращают массив, да не он ни капли не похож.

Последний и самый вменяемый результат - через LockPits(хотя бы размер массива правильный выдает), но значения не те(в центре 255 должно быть много в черно-белом), а в итоге и за сотку не заходит.

**Это фукнция для преобразования**

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(Bitmap bmp)
{
    var pxf = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;

    // Получаем данные картинки.
    var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    //Блокируем набор данных изображения в памяти
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);

    // Получаем адрес первой линии.
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    // Задаём массив из Byte и помещаем в него надор данных.
    // int numBytes = bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 3; 
    //На 3 умножаем - поскольку RGB цвет кодируется 3-мя байтами
    //Либо используем вместо Width - Stride
    int numBytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
    int widthBytes = bmpData.Stride;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];

    // Копируем значения в массив.
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);

    return rgbValues;
}
```

**Это основной код**

```
 ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
 var current_bimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("(gray).jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
 int widthX=current_bimage.PixelWidth;
 int heightY=current_bimage.PixelHeight;
 byte[] bData = imageToByteArray(new Bitmap("(gray).jpg"));
 //System.Drawing.Image asdfa = new Bitmap("./(gray).jpg");

 var count_bData=bData.Count();
 //List<MyPoint> points = new List<MyPoint>();
 byte max=255;
 Stack<int> X = new Stack<int>();
 Stack<int> Y = new Stack<int>();
 int ara;
 int c_pixels = 0;
 int y;
 int x;
 int i = -3;
 for (y = 0; y < heightY; y++)
 {
     x = 0;
     for (x = 0; x < widthX; x=x+1)
     {
         var mid = ( bData[y * x]);
         // var mid = (30 * bData[y * x] + 59 * bData[y * x + 1] + 11 * bData[y * x + 2]) / 100;
         //Console.WriteLine(y + " " + x + " " + mid + bData[y * x] + bData[y * x + 1] +  bData[y * x + 2]);
         if (mid == max)
         {
             Y.Push(y);
             X.Push(x);
             c_pixels++;
         }
     }
 }
 var midX = X.Sum() / c_pixels;
 var midY = Y.Sum() / c_pixels;
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что угадали с форматом?

Comment: Чему равно `bmp.PixelFormat`?

Comment: `var mid = ( bData[y * x]);` — неправильно. Должно быть `var midR = bData[y * Stride + x * 3]; var midG = bData[y * Stride + x * 3 + 1]; var midB = bData[y * Stride + x * 3 + 2];`

Comment: @VladD Нет, поэтому я попробовал все предлагаемые форматы. Заработало, спасибо большое. Я правильно понимаю, что Stride задает шаг, через который находятся значения пикселей?

Comment: `Stride` задаёт размер одной строки в _байтах_. Если сработало, напишу в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что ошибка в коде

```
var mid = ( bData[y * x]);
```

Должно быть так:

```
var midR = bData[y * Stride + x * 3];
var midG = bData[y * Stride + x * 3 + 1];
var midB = bData[y * Stride + x * 3 + 2];
```

Пояснение: `Stride` задаёт размер строки в байтах, поэтому `y * Stride` — номер начального байта для `y`-ой строки. Каждый пиксель занимает по 3 байта в формате `Format24bppRgb`, поэтому нам нужен байт в строке со смещением `x * 3`, и два следующих за ним.